# .NET: Random number or number of free bytes in memory?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, random

How can I get the number of free bytes available in memory, in .NET?

Also, can you think of a potentially better random number beside `new Random().Next()`, `DateTime.Now.Ticks`, or available system memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your question regarding memory metrics, look into using performance counters.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
PerformanceCounter counter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available Bytes");
long freeBytes = counter.RawValue;
```

You may end up needing to use a different counter, such as "Memory\Free & Zero Page List Bytes," to get what you want.  I recommend experimenting with the performance counters in perfmon.

Answer (score 2):

That might work better as 2 questions...

Re `new Random().Next()` - that will obviously die in a tight loop, so an *existing* `random.Next()` would be more random ;-p But you **perhaps** want a cryptographic random - something like:

```
    var random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    random.GetBytes(bytes);
    int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
```

Note that this makes testing harder though, as it can't be seeded etc...

Answer (score 1):

Why re-invent the wheel when there is a very nice one available here: [Random.org](http://www.random.org/) ?

> RANDOM.ORG offers true random numbers
>   to anyone on the Internet. The
>   randomness comes from atmospheric
>   noise, which for many purposes is
>   better than the pseudo-random number
>   algorithms typically used in computer
>   programs. People use RANDOM.ORG for
>   holding drawings, lotteries and
>   sweepstakes, to drive games and
>   gambling sites, for scientific
>   applications and for art and music.

**Disclaimer:** I am not affiliated in any way with this site, nor can I vouch for the quality of what they offer. I just personally think it is a pretty cool idea.